# Yii2 not exist валидатор

Tags: php, yii2, валидация

Появилась необходимость перед сохранением модели проверять наличие связей.
Например, перед пометкой товара "удалено" нужно проверить наличие этого товара в корзине покупателя или в составе незавершенного заказа в процессинге магазина.

Использовать unique валидатор для этого или можно как-то настроить exist, что бы он не срабатывал, если найдены записи?

Comment: Можете создать свой собственный класс для валидации если не хотите заморачиваться с псевдо-кодом проверок. Наследуете от ExistValidator и прописываете метод validateAttribute

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Я так и сделал, правда, пришлось скопипастить несколько приватных методов. По этому поводу уже открыл issue в репе Yii2